# How to get the lowest ID present for each category SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables is sql

**Diagnosis**

```
DiagnosisID
DiagnosisDescription
```

**Member**

```
MemberID
FirstName
LastName
```

**DiagnosisCategoryMap**

```
DiagnosisCategoryID
DiagnosisID
```

**MemberDiagnosis**

```
MemberID
DiagnosisID
```

What I need to do is find the diagnosis with the lowest DiagnosisID present for each Members Category

This is the sql I have so far:

```
SELECT MD.MemberID AS MID,
  MD.DiagnosisID AS DID,
  DM.DiagnosisCategoryID AS CID
FROM
  MemberDiagnosis MD
    INNER JOIN DiagnosisCategoryMap DM ON MD.DiagnosisID = DM.DiagnosisID
```

Which gives me this result set:

```
> MID  DID  CID
>  1    2    2
>  1    4    3
>  3    3    3
>  3    4    3
```

The result set I need should look like this:

```
> MID   DID   CID
   1     2     2
   3     3     3
```

What am I missing in my query.

I have tried to do a group by but that (of course) did not work out well because I could not aggregate properly for the group by.

I am using SQL SERVER and that is all I can use

Comment: I don't think your question matches your expected results. Your first table (minus the last record) would be the lowest DiagnosisID present for each Members Category.

Comment: I agree with you Ross but the answer was presented the way I needed it.  Sorry if I was not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `MIN` aggregate to get the minimum DiagnosticID for each MemberID and DiagnosisCategoryID using GROUP BY

```
SELECT MD.MemberID AS MID,
  MIN(MD.DiagnosisID) AS DID,
  DM.DiagnosisCategoryID AS CID
FROM
  MemberDiagnosis MD
  INNER JOIN DiagnosisCategoryMap DM ON MD.DiagnosisID = DM.DiagnosisID
GROUP BY
    MD.MemberID,
    DM.DiagnosisCategoryID
```

Comment: Thank you this solution works perfectly for what I am needing

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down into smaller steps.

First, verify that you can get the lowest Diagnosis Id for each Member with the following:

```
select MemberId as MID, min(DiagnosisId) as DID
from MemberDiagnosis
group by MemberId
```

When you have verified that that works, join the DiagnosisCategoryMap table...

```
select MID, DID, DiagnosisCategoryId as CID
from
(
    select MemberId as MID, min(DiagnosisId) as DID
    from MemberDiagnosis
    group by MemberId
) src
inner join DiagnosisCategoryMap dcm
    on dcm.DiagnosisId = src.DID
```

Comment: This gives the record associated with each members minimum diagnosis id, not the minimum diagnosis id for each member's category. In other words, with this query we'd drop any category with a diagnosis ID above the minimum.

Comment: Also this returns a Boolean error on the join.  Not sure why

Comment: @Error_2646, the desired result set illustrated by the OP seemed to indicate that the category should drop out of the GroupBy.

Comment: @Max, that error is generally a result of a field type mismatch between the fields in the join.  You might want to make sure those field types match.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID AS MID,  MIN(C.DiagnosisID) AS DID, C.DiagnosisCategoryID AS CID
FROM 
Member A INNER JOIN MemberDiagnosis B
ON A.MemberID=B.MemberID
INNER JOIN DiagnosisCategoryMap C
ON B.DiagnosisID=C.DiagnosisID
GROUP BY A.ID, C.DiagnosisCategoryID;
```

Comment: This is very close but it returns nulls and I do not want that.

Comment: Use inner join then @Max